# How to hide toolbar after collapsing while recyclerView scrolling down

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-support-design

How to hide toolbar after collapsing while recyclerView scrolling down, show toolbar when recyclerView scrolling up, and expand CollapsingToolbarLayout at the end of list? Now CollapsingToolbarLayout just collapse, and toolbar is showing all time when scrolling.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#229944"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: may be removing `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` should work. Just an idea.

Answer (score 3):

This should work perfectly. Tested and working in API 17

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/careers_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activity.CareersActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/main_color_white"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change the behaviour of the Toolbar. You can provide scroll behaviour by changing layout_scrollFlags.

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Remove `pin` and make this change in your Toolbar and it would work!

Answer (score 0):

- Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in `CoordinatorLayout`.
- Remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"` from `Toolbar`.
- Move `TabLayout` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

  ```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

      <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
          android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
          app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
          app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="180dp"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:background="#229944"
              android:contentDescription="@null"
              android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
              android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
              app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

          <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
              android:id="@+id/tabs"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

      </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
  ```

Comment: It doesn't work( Toolbar show anyway. And tabBar overlay toolbar, because  CollapsingToolbarLayout is FrameLayout.

Comment: @preceptron in your code, it doesn't shows any sign of `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

For `CollapsingToolbarLayout` use scroll flags:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAllwaysCollapsed"
```

this flag combination will disappear toolbar while scrolling down. And `CollapsingToolbarLayout` will expand fully when you scroll to top of the list.

And no need to remove `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` from `Toolbar`, because `collapseMode` flags are to define behavior and placement of views inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and will not effect actual collapsing and expansion of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.